# No consigo hacer una transición al mostrar elemento

Tags: css3

Buenas,

Tengo un pequeño script que me muestra la cabecera de la web (menú) al hacer scroll hacia arriba. Cuando eso ocurre añado una clase con la posición `fixed`, sin embargo soy incapaz de agregar una animación a esa transición.

Código HTML:

```
 <header class="web-menu">

        <nav class="menu">
            <ul>

                <li><a href="http://vivexbox.com">VIVEXBOX</a></li>
                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">LISTADO JUEGOS</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="pagina_principal_precios.php">Índice</a></li>
                        <li><a href="listado_precios.php">Xbox One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="xbox360.php">Xbox 360</a></li>
                        <li><a href="retro.php">Retrocompatibles</a></li>
                        <li><a href="DWG.php">Deals With Gold</a></li>
                        <!--- <li><a href="Winter_Sales.php">Ofertas de Navidad</a></li> --->
                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">LISTADO DE PRECIOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="foro.php">FORO</a></li>
                <li><a href="contacto.php">CONTACTO</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
</header>
```

Jquery:

```
var $web_menu =  $('.web-menu');
var $win = $(window);
var $ultimo_scroll = 0;

$win.on('scroll', function(){
    var $altura = $win.scrollTop()

    if ($ultimo_scroll > $altura && $altura > 400) {
        $web_menu.addClass('header_fijo');
    } else {
        $web_menu.removeClass('header_fijo');
    }

    $ultimo_scroll = $altura;
});
```

CSS3:

```
header
{
height:130px;
background:#000;
width:100%;
z-index:150;
position:relative;
color:#fff;
background-image: url("https://s1.postimg.org/s1y5lzgxr/header_largo.png");
}

.web-menu {
position: inherit;
}

.header_fijo {
position: fixed;
transition: position 250ms;
}
```

Comment: La propiedad `position` no es animable. ¿Qué tipo de animación quieres hacer? ¿Qué se traslade? En ese caso necesitas animar las propiedades `left` y `top`.

Comment: Leches, no lo sabía. Simplemente quiero que el menú aparezca cuando se hace scroll hacia arriba, cosa que hace, pero lo hace de forma muy brusca, quería que fuese algo más suave la transición de "aparecer" y "desaparecer".

Answer (score 0):

Buenas JetLagFox, el problema de tu código reside en varios aspectos:

1- La comprobación dentro de la clausula if.

Si añades

```
...
alert($ultimo_scroll+" > "+$altura+" && "+$altura+" > "+400)        
if ($ultimo_scroll > $altura && $altura > 400) {
...
```

Podrás ir viendo cada uno de los valores tal que así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los valores casi nunca cumplen la condición.

2- Además , hay un error con el uso de jquery, principalmente porque la declaración del objeto jquery es posterior a la selección del elemento 'web-menu', y esto provoca que no funcione el add class y el remove class.

3- También no tienes cerradas correctamente tus etiquetas header,  justo antes de la etiqueta de cierre hay dos de cierre de div perdidas.

Sin embargo tu código css sí que está correcto y si añades la clase **header_fijo** funciona correctamente.

Para arreglarlo puedes englobar tu código en un callback que sirve para ejecutar el código solo cuando todo el documento está correctamente cargado

```
$(function(){

   var $web_menu =  $('.web-menu');
   var $win = $(window); 

   $win.on('scroll', function(){

    var $altura = $win.scrollTop()

            //ya solo tienes que corregir el if  
    //comprobando a tu gusto
    if ( $altura > 200) {
        $web_menu.addClass('header_fijo');
    } else {
        $web_menu.removeClass('header_fijo');
    } 
  });

});
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Lo he probado pero no hace lo que quiero. Lo que quiero es que el header se muestre cuando se haga scroll hacia arriba, cosa que pasa, pero quería cambiar la animación de cuando el header aparece y desapacer porque es demasiado brusca.

Comment: @JetLagFox para que no sea demasiado brusca puedes animar con css. Pero como te dicen abajo , la propiedad position no es animable. En cambio puedes animar otras propiedades dando le el efecto deseado como dice el compañero Gustavo

Comment: @JetLagFox otra idea sin usar opacity sería posicionarlo a top: -XXpx;  y animar luego a top: 0px; daría el efecto de movimiento, ¿puedes dar un ejemplo del tipo de transición que quieres ?  a ver si te podemos ayudar  :)

Comment: Perdón por la demora. He probado con opacidad y no funciona mal del todo, aunque no me acabad de convencer porque sigue siendo brusco el movimiento. No he probado todavía a darle movimiento como el que comentas, a ver si saco tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

¿Por qué habrías de ver una animación si intentas animar la propiedad `position` cuando **ésta no es animable**? Es lógico que no veas ninguna animación.

> Simplemente quiero que el menú aparezca cuando se hace scroll hacia arriba, cosa que hace, pero lo hace de forma muy brusca, quería que fuese algo más suave la transición de "aparecer" y "desaparecer".

Entonces, lo que te sirve es animar `opacity`. Cuando bajes el scroll y el menú salga de vista, dale una opacidad de `0`. Luego, cuando lo muestras, añade primero `header_fijo` y quita `header_oculto`, clase que solo cambia la opacidad a `0`.

**CSS**

```
header {
  height: 130px;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 150;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: url("https://s1.postimg.org/s1y5lzgxr/header_largo.png");
  transition: opacity .35s ease .2s;
}

.header_oculto {
  opacity: 0;
}

.web-menu {
  position: inherit;
}

.header_fijo {
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
// si el scroll pasó el header, añades 'header_oculto'
if (...) {
  $web_menu.removeClass('header_oculto');
}

if ($ultimo_scroll > $altura && $altura > 400) {
  $web_menu.addClass('header_fijo');
  $web_menu.removeClass('header_oculto');
} else {
  $web_menu.addClass('header_oculto');
  window.setTimemout(function () {
    $web_menu.removeClass('header_fijo');
  }, 350); // .35s duración de la animación de opacidad
}
```